# when I do a geocoder I get this crash with the following errortext: "System.ArgumentNullException, argument cannot be null"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I'm doing an geocoder and I have trouble with my string (that has a value) and I get this error:

> "System.ArgumentNullException, argument cannot be null"

Code below:

```
async void loadItem ()
    {
    var getItems = await parseAPI.getOurMainInfo (Application.Current.Properties ["sessionToken"].ToString ());

        foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

        infoString = currentItem ["ourInfoDatabase"].ToString (); //gets stored on the database.
        }

var info = infoString; //it says i get the error here. 
// my string is not empty/null. 
// when I run it in system.diagnostics.debug.writeline it gives me a value and it gets stored on the database.

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder ();
        Task<IEnumerable<Position>> result =
            gc.GetPositionsForAddressAsync (info);

        IEnumerable<Position> data = await result;

        foreach (Position p in data) {

        }
 }
```

Can I make a code that prevents the crash?

Comment: Just Place Debug point and Pls check that what value you get in 

`var info = infoString; //it says i get the error here. 
Console.WriteLine("Val Info"+ info);`

Comment: yeah it does not get the value but what if I sometimes the value is null? Can a make a code to prevent a crash somehow?

Comment: or like do something with if =! null () {run code?}

Comment: yeah my code above solved it :) sweet